# Mysql equality against false or true

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In the following query:

```
select count(1) from main_territory where code = true
union all
select count(1) from main_territory where code = false;

-------------------------------------------------------------------
count(1)
0
250
```

Why does putting `0` or `false` make the query return all rows?

It doesn't matter what the data is, but here's a sample:

```
CREATE TABLE z_tmp (x varchar(11));
insert into z_tmp values ('x'); -- note this is not a Boolean
select count(1) from z_tmp where x=true union all select count(1) from z_tmp where x=false;
```

Note: I'm using mysql5.7.

Comment: It would help to see sample data.  You are assuming we know what's in the table; we don't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The data doesn't matter. I've updated it though to give you a sample.

Comment: In your second example, the integer value 1 gets coerced to `'1'` during the insert.  This value is truthy and so is true.  Not much happening here either than coercions of type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry that was a typo, please see the question now.

Comment: `UNION` joins the two queries' results. You've selected all the rows where `x=true`, and all the rows where `x=false`. If it's a boolean column, that's all of them.

Comment: Could you please clarify? I'm basically just wondering why doing `column=false` returns all results, regardless of what column is.

Comment: It is because the varchar literals are being casted to false.  If they don't start with `1` the cast will be to false.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh, I see. That seems a bit odd, I'd think that the opposite might happen -- the boolean would be cast to a string. Is that considered odd syntax in mysql or do most other DBs do that as well?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen btw, you can post an answer with that and I can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, `true` is literally the integer 1 and `false` is the integer 0. This is non-standard and not similar to some other SQL implementations, but this is the way MySQL works.

```
mysql> select true, false;
+------+-------+
| true | false |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

When you compare an integer to a string, the string is cast to its integer value, which is based on any leading digit characters in the string. If it has no leading digits, the integer value is 0.

So you're comparing `0 = 1` and `0 = 0`:

```
mysql> select 'x' = 1, 'x' = 0;
+---------+---------+
| 'x' = 1 | 'x' = 0 |
+---------+---------+
|       0 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

All the rows where `x` has no leading digits evaluate as 0, and therefore are equal to `false`.

Comment: thanks, that seems quite weird. Do you know of any other DB systems that try and convert the string to a boolean based on its leading char being `1` or not?

Comment: It's not converting to a boolean, it's converting to a numeric. In standard SQL, casting a string to a number fails with an error if the string does not contain a valid numeric format (with optional leading whitespace). Cf. https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/07.html#cast

Comment: @David542 MySQL is perhaps the most lax SQL database syntax wise.  Strictly speaking, comparing a string directly to a boolean is non sensical.  On other databases, you might have gotten an error, or even different behavior.

Comment: Yeah, you're _supposed_ to get an error, because in standard SQL, there's a genuine `BOOL` data type, and it's not the same as an integer. But in MySQL it is. You can use logical comparisons in arithmetic expressions: `SUM(mycolumn = 1234)` which sums 1 for rows where the expression is "true." This throws an error in other SQL implementations. You would have to do `SUM(CASE mycolumn WHEN 1234 THEN 1 END)` to map the boolean result to an integer 1.